# "\n" not getting recognised while reading from file

Tags: c++

Beginner here so please bear with me. So I am reading data from a csv file and I need to read data word by word and stop at the end of the line. This is the code.

```
fstream fops;
fops.open("file.csv");
string s;
do
{ 
  fops>>s;
}while(s!="\n");
```

However the loop continues to the next line until the file ends. Please help me out on this

Comment: `operator>>()` ignores whitespace. Use  `getline()` instead to read an entire line. Alternatively, find a library to read and parse CSV files.

Comment: Initially I did use getline(fops,s,'\n'). But I want to read it word by word so that I can assign each word to another variable.

Comment: Related ( help for reading csv files): [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120140/how-can-i-read-and-parse-csv-files-in-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120140/how-can-i-read-and-parse-csv-files-in-c)

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Stop answering in comments

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I need to read data word by word and stop at the end of the line.

```
#include <sstream> // std::stringstream

fstream fops("file.csv");
if(fops) { // file opened
    string line;
    string word;
    // while(std::getline(fops, line)) { // to read all lines
    if(std::getline(fops, line)) {       // to read one line
        std::istringstream is(line);     // put the line in a stringstream
        while(is >> word) {              // extract word-by-word
            // use word
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`operator>>()` ignores whitespace. Use `getline()` instead to read an entire line. Alternatively, find a library to read and parse CSV files.

> I want to read it word by word so that I can assign each word to another variable.

With `operator>>()` you cannot differentiate between a space `' '` and a new line `'\n'`. You should read an entire line and then parse the line into "words".